# Displaying two different data types from an object in a Listview

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap, simpleadapter

Basically, I'm looking to populate a ListView with the value "test", and the value "createdAt". I've figured out how to get either one show up in listview, but not both. There's obviously something I don't understand about how this works at a pretty fundamental level. I don't know how to get two different data types (string, and Date) to show up together in the same ListView element. I know SimpleAdapter needs a List containing a map, but if I can only store one key, value pair in a map, how can I display more than one value at a time?

```
        public void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, Date>> messages= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Date>>();
                for (ParseObject result : results) {
                    HashMap<String, Date> testMap = new HashMap<String,Date>();
                    HashMap<String, String> dateMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

                    testMap.put("test",(String)result.get("test"));

                    dateMap.put(createdAtKey,(Date)result.getCreatedAt());

                    messages.add(message);
                                            //What do I do with the "test"values?

                }
                SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(FeedActivity.this, messages,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] {testKey,createdAtKey}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 });
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught!", e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to create your own Adapter that subclass BaseAdapter, then you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're passing the right data into your adapter but cannot manage to display it.

First - you need to create a XML file which will represent the layout that populates your list view. For example, assuming that text1 and text2 are the ids of textboxes that should display your results, I'd do it like this:

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/layoutContainer" >
    <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/text1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Inisde your activity, use the String[] values to achieve target format:

```
String[] values = new String[testMap.size];
for(int i=0;i<testMap.size;i++) {
    values[i] = "[" + testMap.get(yourKey) + "]-[" + dateMap.get(yourKey) + "]" //replace yourKey with the appropriate key string
CustomAdapter myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), values);
```

Then implement a CustomAdapter class, like this

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private String[] data;
    private Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = values;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }
    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data[position];
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View adapterView = convertView;
        if (adapterView == null) {
            adapterView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }
        TextView text1 = (TextView) adapterView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        text1.setText(data[position]);
        return adapterView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm absolutely passing the right data. I logged everything (removed from the paste) and the data is there. I can also correctly display either the Date (which works) and the test value (which also works) but not both at the same time. So i'll give this a shot and see what happens.

Comment: Am I supposed to create a new class like myAdapter and extend SimpleAdapter?

Comment: Yep, but extend `BaseAdapter` not `SimpleAdapter`

Comment: Alright, pretty confused now. So, am I still using a mapping, or am I simply saving the object data into arrays? Can't a hashmap still only take one kind of value? Am I supposed to pass both maps somehow?

Comment: In the code I provided, I assume that `testKey[]` array contains the data that corresponds to testMap, more precisely its key value and the `getCreatedAt[]` array contains the data that coressponds to dateMap, more precisely its key value. Is that what you wanted in your original question?

Comment: Basically, I have a ParseObject containing a string (called "test") and a date. I need to populate a list with "[Test]-[Date]" in every list item, by whichever means possible.

Comment: Finally I get it. You need to use string formatter to create a single String array with `[Test]-[Date]` format and then pass that array to your adapter. Wait for me to update my answer.